# In admin some urls "?SID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" are coming and it move to login page of admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, login

I am working in admin and some weird time in URL "?SID=XXXXXXXXXXXX" are coming and then Login page is open on that url. But admin is login. Here XXXXXXXXXXX are some alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Do you want to remove SID from url ?

Comment: I am not getting why this is happening, if admin is login from other page and when i click on manage products page then it display ?SID in url with login page.

Comment: And it is issue in Windows machine only this time.

Answer (score 0):

The SID is a "session ID". Magento uses this ID to track a user's activity
within the same Magento installation. Normally, Magento powers one website and one store from one installation (database).

Magento could power multiple websites with multiple stores from one
installation, though. The SID allows users to stay logged in while
navigating across these websites/stores.

I think if you have the function enabled, the SID is sent while accessing
catalog URLs so Magento can update the session with the user's
location/state for the current website/store.

If you're not running a multi-website or multi-store environment, it's
safe to disable the SID on the frontend, the ___SID=U is used in the cache as a placeholder for the session ID. It is replaced by Mage_Core_Model_Url::sessionUrlVar() which in turn calls Mage_Core_Model_Url::sessionVarCallback(). These methods are called from Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::_afterCacheUrl(), which means that any URL found in block output will contain the correct session ID (if needed).

So to get rid of the parameter in your own code the "right way" use this:

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('some/magento/route'); // might append ___SID parameter
$url = Mage::getModel('core/url')->sessionUrlVar($url); // process ___SID
```

If the string is displaying in the rendered page that is a bug. Are you
using some custom caching module, or generating URL's using a non-standard way?